# How do I move a vert on my uvs that's overlaying another vert without moving both of them?

Tags: texturing, uv, vertices, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

As the title says I have a vert overlaying another vert in the uv image editor and I would like to be able to move one of them without moving the other one.

Comment: maybe click twice on the vertex?

Comment: You can H hide the elements you don't want moved. either in the map, or the model.(Usual combinations .. Alt-H Unhide, Shift-H Hide inverted selection)